# Consolidate csv data in ruby to get totals/sums of unique values

Tags: ruby, csv

I'm still struggling with a basic problem I have not found an answer to online.

I am getting CSV like data as name and quantity:

```
Foo, 1.5
Bar, 1.2
Foo, 1.1
...
```

And want to consolidate it to unique names with the totals as a new value:

```
Foo, 2.6   #total of both Foo lines
Bar, 1.2
...
```

Every single time the data set is not large, but the task is quite repetitive.

I tried to convert it into an array of hashes, finding `uniq` names, and then use `inject`, but somehow it got quite complicated and did not work. Also, looping through everything seems not to be the ideal approach.

Does anyone have a nice and easy idea or solution I am missing? (I only found "[Extract value from row in csv and sum it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16114530/extract-value-from-row-in-csv-and-sum-it)" for PHP.)

Comment: It's important to show your attempt towards solving the problem. As is, it appears you want someone to do your work for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you can use Ruby's [CSV](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) library to parse and convert your CSV data:

```
require 'csv'

csv_data = "Foo, 1.5\nBar, 1.2\nFoo, 1.1"

data_array = CSV.parse(csv_data, converters: :numeric)
#=> [["Foo", 1.5], ["Bar", 1.2], ["Foo", 1.1]]
```

To sum the values I'd use a hash along with [`each_with_object`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object):

```
data_array.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |(k, v), h| h[k] += v }
#=> {"Foo"=>2.6, "Bar"=>1.2}
```

Comment: Very nice solutions...Every answers has taken csv data as already an Array..But you did Parse it first to convert it in Array..Which is actually correct1+

Comment: Thank you very much, that's absolutely perfect and works like a charm! Much more efficient than what I was fiddling with... :)

Comment: @GaganGami not every answer assumed that! ;)

Answer (score 1):

The array of hash seems to be the easiest approach:

Let's say that:

```
CSV=[["foo",1.5],["bar",2.2],["foo",1.1]]
```

Just do:

```
myCSV=[["foo",1.5],["bar",1.2],["foo",1.1]]
myCSV.each_with_object(Hash.new(0.0)){|row,sum| sum[row[0]]+=row[1]}
=> {
  "foo" => 2.6,
  "bar" => 1.2
}
```

If you are reading from a file, it's more or less the same using the CSV library:

```
sum=Hash.new(0.0)
CSV.foreach("path/to/file.csv") do |row|
  sum[row[0]]+=row[1]
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Passing `0.0` as the [default](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Hash.html#method-c-new) option for your Hash accounts nicely for the first occurrence of each item:

```
input = [ ['Foo', 1.5],
          ['Bar', 1.2],
          ['Foo', 1.1] ]

result = input.inject(Hash.new(0.0)) do |sum, (key, value)|
  sum[key] += value
  sum
end

p result
```